# passing and setting TextView from another class

Tags: java, android, textview

I have a text view in my android activity, and I want to pass it to a function in another java class and modify its text. But it throws me an exception. I read that I need to run it on a UI thread or send to context variable, but I'm a bit confused and I couldn't manage to do it. That's my code:

Java timer class

```
public class CountdownTimer {
static int duration;
static Timer timer;

public static void startTimer(final TextView TVtime) {
    duration = 10;

    timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        public void run() {
            TVtime.setText(setDuration());
        }
    }, 1000, 1000);
}

private static String setDuration(){
    if(duration == 1)
        timer.cancel();
    return String.valueOf(--duration);
}
}
```

Android activity:

```
TVtime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_displayTime);
CountdownTimer.startTimer(TVtime);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [android.os.Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) for that :

```
public static void startTimer(final TextView TVtime) {
    duration = 10;

    final Handler handler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            TVtime.setText((String) msg.obj);
        }
    };

    timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        public void run() {
            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.obj = setDuration();
            handler.sendMessage(msg);
        }
    }, 1000, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot update the UI from a non-UI Thread. Pass the `activity` `Context` to the `startTimer()` method.

```
public static void startTimer(final TextView TVtime,final Context activityContext) {
    duration = 10;

    timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

       public void run() {
          ((Activity) activityContext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run()
                {
                     TVtime.setText(setDuration());
                }
            });
..........................
.......................
```

Android activity:

```
TVtime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_displayTime);
CountdownTimer.startTimer(TVtime, YourActivity.this);
```

Comment: for some reason it says that activityContext doesn't have the method runOnUiThread

Comment: Forgot to mention that. You have to cast it to `Activity`. See the updated answer.

Comment: I didn' try it but thanks anyway, I used the handler solution. Do you know any advantages\disadvantages of one over the other?

Comment: Refer this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618038/why-to-use-handlers-while-runonuithread-does-the-same

Using `runOnUiThread` ensures that your code will run in the UI thread.